# App Visibility Migrating Apple Developer Account from Individual to Business

Tags: ios, apple-developer, app-store-connect

I currently have an individual developer account that I'm considering migrating to a business account since i've recently formed a legal entity.

I have a few apps on the App Store that are doing very well and have been continually climbing on the charts (for their respective categories)

I am wondering if migrating my account will have any effect, positive or negative, on the visibility of my apps? Will my rankings suddenly slip because my "Individual" developer name is no longer associated with the app? Does this "reset" some ASO?

I've tried asking Apple, but they gave me a generic response:

> "During the migration, the applications will remain on the App Store. No changes will be noticeable for the users. Since the account information will be refreshed, the ranking of the app on the App Store is not guaranteed."

This makes me a bit worried. It almost seems as this will negatively affect my apps.

Has anyone had experience with this? Did it turn out well?

Answer (score 0):

The migration had absolutely no effect on my apps performance! The process was also very quick (~3 hours).